# SQL difference between host_name and hostname from sys.sysprocesses

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between these two queries:

```
select hostname,* from sys.sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID;
select host_name()
```

Likely the second one, requires less permission to user executing query.

Comment: Whilst learning T-SQL, bear in mind that it's a language with a lot of history to it and it's been steered in a number of different directions over the years (both for attempting to follow standards or just trying to follow a current trend). This means that there are often *multiple ways of retrieving the same information*. I'd suggest you *shouldn't* automatically assume that the existence of multiple options means that they must have subtle (or non-subtle) differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference from permissions point of view. Both queries can be executed having no permissions at all.

From [sys.sysprocesses (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql):

> If a user has `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server, the user
> will see all executing sessions in the instance of SQL Server;
> **otherwise, the user will see only the current session**.

In both cases the scope is current session only so there is no difference, and no permission is required.